# How to disable Kibana 8.x plugins?

Tags: kibana, kibana-8

I've tried all possible solutions:

in /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
xpack.ml.enabled: false
xpack.fleet.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
xpack.maps.enabled: false
xpack.sql.enabled: false

And it telling that configuration key is invalid. (also tried without xpack. and also without .enabled)

bin/kibana-plugin tell me that there are no plugins installed.

However within kibana logs I have lots of mentions:
][plugins.usageCollection.usage-collection.collector-set] Unable to fetch data from monitoringTelemetry collector
[plugins.cloudSecurityPosture] Failed to get index stats for .alerts-security.alerts-default: TimeoutError: Request timed out

How do I disable all these plugins?